# Set overflow adjust height

Tags: html, css

i have structure html, example like this :
[image]

i am using this code :

```
<section id="home" >
    <div id="first">
        <div class="top-img">
          <img src="img/home-top.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-img">
          <img src="img/home-down.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

the problem is, i want to scrolling only until the half of the second picture. because, next i want to when user click the second image and second image be scrolltop offset. i do not know how to work it..

Comment: You have to use scrolltop in jquery. https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: a big problem is, how to make a scrolling only until the half of the second image. scrolltop only my reason why i create it.. :)

Comment: count the first image height and secong image height. First image height + (second image height / 2) = scrolltop.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery provide a [scroll handler](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily) you will be able to stop the scroll.

1) handle the scroll
2) when the user is near your anchor stop the scroll